# Devextreme JS - How to draw a line between 2 markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, polyline, bing

I am using javascript devextreme. I want to draw a line between 2 markers. (Not the route) But I was not successful. I need to draw 2 lines as in the example picture. Devextreme JS - How to draw a line between 2 markers?

```
$(() => {
  const markerUrl = 'https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/JSDemos/images/maps/map-marker.png';
  const markersData = [{
    location: [40.755833, -73.986389],
    tooltip: {
      text: 'Times Square',
    },
  }, {
    location: '40.7825, -73.966111',
    tooltip: {
      text: 'Central Park',
    },
  }, {
    location: { lat: 40.753889, lng: -73.981389 },
    tooltip: {
      text: 'Fifth Avenue',
    },
  }, {
    location: 'Brooklyn Bridge,New York,NY',
    tooltip: {
      text: 'Brooklyn Bridge',
    },
  },
  ];

  const mapWidget = $('#map').dxMap({
    provider: 'bing',
    apiKey: {
      bing: 'Aq3LKP2BOmzWY47TZoT1YdieypN_rB6RY9FqBfx-MDCKjvvWBbT68R51xwbL-AqC',
    },
    zoom: 11,
    height: 440,
    width: '100%',
    controls: true,
    markerIconSrc: markerUrl,
    markers: markersData,
  }).dxMap('instance');

 
});
```